# How to check if a module needs an update using comands/code?

Tags: module, upgrade, rest-api

Is there a way to check if a module needs an update using commands or code ?

Maybe i can compare the current version to the latest version, but how do i check what the latest version for a module is ?

Is there a Magento API where a user can get infos about a module ? (current version, latest version, description, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through composer with:

```
composer outdated
```

This will give you the list of modules that require an update.

If you want something automated, you can write a small script to send the result by email, ran time to time with a cronjob.